# Count occurrences in objects and record the number when the sequence is broken

Tags: javascript, arrays

Apologies in advance if this has been asked, I've found similar questions but not quite what I've needed.

Basically I have a huge array of objects, simplified it looks like this:

```
var objects = [
{age: '32', id: '2'},
{age: '56', id: '1'},
{age: '23', id: '2'},
{age: '45', id: '2'},
{age: '48', id: '2'},
{age: '67', id: '1'},
{age: '36', id: '2'},
{age: '45', id: '1'},
]
```

I need to go through all objects and look at the id, if the id is 2, I need  to start counting how many times 2 appears in sequence before the sequence is interrupt by another id(1 in the example).

So in the example above the result would be:

(in the format "times in a row": "count")
one time: 2
three times: 1

Comment: I don't understand your result, what does it mean? Also could you provide what you tried so far?

Comment: The result means that ID in the array started with 2, one time in a row two times(the first object and the second last), and three times in a row one time.(The bunch in the middle).

Comment: `2` occurs 5 times, `1` occurs 3 times. I see no magic here

Comment: Im only intressted in ID 2, and how many times they appear in sequence. It occurs 3 times in sequence one time, and 1 time in sequence two times.

Comment: This is so obscure!

Comment: Not really, but maybe my restricted english is making it hard to explain.

Comment: @Subsack I think I understan now. I made a function that do what you want. I just want to know how you want the result to be? Do you want is as an object like this: `{"3": 1, "1": 2}`?

Comment: That would be fine :)

Comment: Or as an array of objects like this: `[{many: 3, count: 1}, {many: 1, count: 2}]`?

Comment: @ibrahim mahrir, any of those are fine really :) Go with whatever you find best

Comment: I posted the code! I'll explain with comments in a moment.

Comment: I had a little mistake, I fixed it! See the part after the `for` loop!

Comment: Please check the last updated answer. I had some little mistakes. I fixed them now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var objects = [
  {age: '32', id: '2'},
  {age: '56', id: '1'},
  {age: '23', id: '2'},
  {age: '45', id: '2'},
  {age: '48', id: '2'},
  {age: '67', id: '1'},
  {age: '36', id: '2'},
  {age: '45', id: '1'}
];

function getStats(arr, id) {
  var hash = {};                          // the count object
  var count = 0;                          // the counter that count how many occurences that happen after each other
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {   // loop through the array
    if(arr[i].id == id) {                 // if this element have the id then increment the count
      count++;
    }
    else if(count) {                      // if not, if count is bigger than 0 then increment the count inside the hash object
      hash[count] = hash[count] || 0;     // if the hash object doesn't have a counter for the current count, then create one
      hash[count]++;                      // increment that counter
      count = 0;                          // reinitialize the counter back to 0
    }
  }
  // add the last count if there is one (so if there is element at the end we won't skip them)
  if(count) {
    hash[count] = hash[count] || 0;
    hash[count]++; 
  }

  return hash;
}

console.log(getStats(objects, 2)); // you can choose any id (here it will print the result for id = 2)
```

Comment: I had a little mistake, I fixed it! See the part after the `for` loop!